# Add Continuous Dates to li ul

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add continuous sequence of Dates to a li through generated date or through an array but unable to do so

I either want to pass a array such as this, `arr = [12,13,14...]` or a method like `myDate.getDate()` to this each function

```js
$(".dateslots li").each(function(myDate.getDate()) {
  $(this).text(myDate.getDate() + 1);
});
```

```html
<ul class="dateslots">
  <li class="leftarrow">&nbsp;</li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li class="rightarrow">&nbsp;</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot pass anything in to an event handler. To achieve what you require you'd need to declare `myDate` as a variable outside of the event handler, to be used within it.

Also note that by adding `1` to the date in each iteration you'll end up with the same value in all `li`. If you want to increment the value try adding the index of the element to the date value. Try this:

```js
var myDate = new Date().getDate();

$(".dateslots li:empty").each(function(i) {
  $(this).text(myDate + i);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="dateslots">
  <li class="leftarrow">&nbsp;</li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li class="rightarrow">&nbsp;</li>
</ul>
```

Note the use of the `:empty` selector to retain the content in the first and last list item

Comment: Why is there no increment on dates? Because a constant of 1 being added to current date

Comment: Because the OP adds `1` to the same value in every iteration. I've update the answer to show how to increment the value

Comment: Absolutely... :)

Answer (score 0):

In case the number of dates is dynamic and comes from an array, you can go this way:

```js
$.fn.setDates = function(dates) {
    return this.each(function(i) {
        var thisList = $(this);
        var newHtml = '';
        $.each(dates, function(d) {
         newHtml += '<li>' + dates[d] + '</li>';
        });
        thisList.find('li:not(.arrow)').remove();
        thisList.find('.leftarrow').after(newHtml);
    });
};
var myDate = [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19];
$(".dateslots").setDates(myDate);
setTimeout(function() {
    myDate = [8, 9, 10];
    $(".dateslots").setDates(myDate);
}, 3000);
```

```css
.dateslots li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.arrow {
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    border-top: 6px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 6px solid transparent;
}
.leftarrow {
    border-right: 10px solid blue;
}
.rightarrow {
    border-left: 10px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="dateslots">
    <li class="arrow leftarrow"></li>
    <li class="arrow rightarrow"></li>
</ul>
```

Also on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/skobaljic/adh8061e/22/).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version where you can disable the arrows depending on the date

```js
const offset = new Date().getDate()-1; // today
$(".dateslots").html(
  `<li class="leftarrow">◀</li>`+
  Array.from(Array(10).keys(), n => `<li>${n + offset + 1}</li>`).join("") + 
  `<li class="rightarrow">▶</li>`
);
```

```css
.dateslots li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="dateslots">
</ul>
```